# Laravel и Plesk панель

Tags: laravel, веб-программирование, plesk

Как правильно развернуть проект Laravel на хостинге с панелью Plesk.
Закинул проект напрямую в коневую папку, папку public закинул отдельно в httpdocs. В итоге вижу только front часть проекта. Как использовать существующую БД проекта MySQL, если в панели доступны только MariaDB и PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно загружаю весь проект на httpdocs папку. В настройках хостинга указываю путь к сайту `httpdocs/public`. И не заморачиваюсь дальше с путями (Если решил отделить public и проект, то и пути нужно прописывать в index.php, server.php и еще файлы (этот метод не использую)).
[image: Пример указывания корневой папки]

Либо можно сделать другим способом. в настройках хостинга указываешь как корневая папка `httpdocs`. При этом проект laravel должен лежать в папке httpdocs. И затем нужно в корневой папке создать `.htaccess` файл с такими данными(чтобы перенаправлял в public папку):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

По поводу разворачивания БД проекта MySQL, и если используешь в проекте у себя на локалке mysql, то и соответственно создать базу данных для проекта и на хостинге. Экспортируешь существующий бд проекта через phpmyadmin (в локалке). А затем в plesk в phpmyadmin импортируешь. И не забудь прописать данные для подключения бд в `.env` файле. И затем лучше закэшировать конфигурационные файлы через `php artisan config:cache`